# Expected value for exponential distribution not adding up

Tags: probability, statistics

The download time for one document through the internet on a lab computer has an average of 25 seconds and that time has an exponential distribution. Find the expected time to download 3 documents.

So judging by the assignment if the download time for a single document has an exponential distribution then:

### $\frac{1}{λ} = 25 => λ = \frac{1}{25}$

Now since we are looking for 3 documents the λ for 3 documents is equaled to:

### $λ = \frac{3}{25}$

Hence the expected value should be equaled to: ***$\frac{25}{3}$*** seconds

However here is my confusion:

Since $\frac{25}{3} < 25$ and we're talking about the expected time to download 3 files then souldn't the expected value be ***grater than 25***?

Comment: Are you downloading them in parallel or one after the other? If you are downloading in parallel, you have to find the expected value of the max of 3 exp RVs. If you are downloading serially, the expected time will simply be 75 sec.

Comment: They are being downloaded serially. Can you please explain why is it max of 3 exp RVs if its parallel and why is it 75 if its serially?

Comment: Let $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ denote the download times. If the download is serial, the total time is $X_1+X_2+X_3$. The expected value is simply the sum of the expected values (linearity of expectation), so 3*25. In parallel, your total time is determined by the document that takes the longest. So the total time is $\max(X_1, X_2, X_3)$. I don't think there is an easy way to compute the expectation directly. You have to compute the distribution first and then integrate to get the expected value.

Comment: The error seems to be in this assertion: "Now since we are looking for 3 documents the $\lambda$ for 3 documents is [equal] to $\lambda = \frac{3}{25}$." Why do you believe that is the correct calculation?

Comment: Because there are 3 documents and if each has an exponential distribution with $ λ = \frac{1}{25}$ then for total exponential distribution $  λ = \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{25} + \frac{1}{25} = \frac{3}{25} $

Comment: @DavidMason The $\lambda$s sum up if you are looking at the $\min$ of the RVs, otherwise no. As I explained above, you have to clarify the manner in which the documents are being downloaded.